# Allow Debian 11/Plasma to adjust brightness using keyboard

Tags: debian, kde-plasma-5

I am unable to adjust the brightness on my laptop. These are the hardware and OS specs:

```
    description: Notebook
    product: 82K6 (LENOVO_MT_82K6_BU_idea_FM_Legion 7 16ITHg6)
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: Legion 7 16ITHg6

    Linux 5.10.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.162-1 (2023-01-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux

    plasmashell 5.20.5
    Qt: 5.15.2
    KDE Frameworks: 5.78.0
    kf5-config: 1.0


  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA104M [GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile / Max-Q]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 latency=0 mode=2560x1600 visual=truecolor xres=2560 yres=1600
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:620-61f memory:6d000000-6dffffff memory:6000000000-61ffffffff memory:6200000000-6201ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:6e080000-6e0fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: iomemory:620-61f iomemory:400-3ff irq:168 memory:622d000000-622dffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

When I press the brightness control buttons on my laptop, the display icon shows up on screen to indicate I am adjusting the brightness, but the brightness does not actually change. This is also true if I adjust the brightness slider from the settings.

Any idea how I can fix this so that I can adjust my brightness?

Comment: You might not be able to use the laptop's dedicated Fn key combo for brightness, but see https://www.pcsuggest.com/adjust-linux-screen-brightness/.